# MYSQL Update Pending Approval

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

I have a website where approved users can update, insert and delete data from a table. All of the final changes, however, must be approved before they are made "live" in the original table. I want the data in the original table to be updated on a case by case basis. What is the best way to go about this from the database side? Is it going to be triggers? Procedures? Transactions?

Is there a way to have a trigger on the main table, whereby, when an update is made, it will appear in the trigger table and not effect the live table?

Currently, my trigger looks like this. It works but it is updating both tables.

```
 DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER TEST_UPDATE
BEFORE UPDATE ON test for each row
BEGIN
INSERT INTO test_changes(PERSONID, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, ADDRESS, CITY, TIME)
VALUES(NEW.PERSONID, NEW.LASTNAME, NEW.FIRSTNAME, NEW.ADDRESS, NEW.CITY, NEW.TIME); 
END
//
```

I am assuming that the actual approval/rejection process will have to be done via an admin page on the website. From what I have read so far, MYSQL cannot prompt users for input.

Thanks!!

Comment: Why not just have an active column and only display once an admin approves/denies via the active column?

Comment: If I understand you're suggestion correctly, I don't think that will work. The data that we have is in a tree structure format, each with a specific URI from a graph database. We want to pull the individual URIs that have changes into a pending approval table and then put them back once approved.

Does that make sense? Am I correct in assuming that your suggestion will not work for tree structure data?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't your application just wont use the data unless the approved column has the correct value. Don't mark it as such until it should be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing this question, I realize I was asking for something that is directly possible with MySQL, at least not to my knowledge. What I ended up doing was creating a pending changes table and then displaying it in an HTML table. The "admin" then goes in and approves or deny changes which will then send the changes to the appropriate tables.

This could have been done in a round about way by using an active / inactive column and then displaying rows based on a column value as suggested above but it is more straightforward to just make two tables with the appropriate data.